# Check html file exist on server using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My ASPX code generated some html files where I just put link for paging like

```
<a href="1.html">First</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="3.html">Next</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="1.html">Previous</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="9.html">Last</a>
```

say if user currently on second page when it press Next moves to 3rd page ...

now issue is when user clicking Next button several times and system is in progress to generate let say 5th page it will show error page.

Is there any way to check from html via javascript to check whether file is present or not?
Kindly help me to pull out from this show stopper issue

Comment: you could request the sites with ajax and check if the status code is not 200

Answer (score 6):

You can use ajax for check file exists or not

Using Jquery

```
$.ajax({
        url:'http://www.example.com/3.html',
        error: function()
        {
           alert('file does not exists');
        },
        success: function()
        {
            alert('file exists');
        }
    });
```

Using Javascript

```
function checkIfRemoteFileExists(fileToCheck)
{
    var tmp=new Image;
    tmp.src=fileToCheck;

    if(tmp.complete)        
        alert(fileToCheck+" is available");        
    else        
     alert(fileToCheck+" is not available");        
}
```

Now to check if file exists or not call js function like this

```
checkIfRemoteFileExists('http://www.yoursite.com/abc.html');​
```

Comment: Keep in mind this answer uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com), a Javascript library. :)

Answer (score 2):

i like to use this  type of script

```
function CheckFileExist(fileToCheck: string) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(fileToCheck).then(res => {
            if (res.status == 404) resolve(false);
            if (res.status == 200) resolve(true);
            return res.text()
        }) 
    })

}
```

and use it

```
 var exists = await CheckFileExist(link);
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! People who do not use Typescript should make sure to change the first line to "function CheckFileExist(fileToCheck) {" though.

Answer (score 0):

- There is an issue with @Sibu's solution: it actually downloads the file (it can be potentionally big, wasting traffic)
- In the 2021, one [should not use jQuery](https://www.google.com/search?q=should+i+use+jquery) in new projects
- native [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) are the way to go today

```
<output id="output"></output>

<script>
// create a non-cached HTTP HEAD request
const fileExists = file =>
  fetch(file, {method: 'HEAD', cache: 'no-store'})
  .then(r => r.status==200);

// check the file existence on the server
// and place the link asynchronously after the response is given
const placeNext = file => fileExists(file).then(yes => output.innerHTML = 
   (yes ? `<a href="3.html">Next</a>` : '')
);

// place the "next" link in the output if "3.html" exists on the server
placeNext('3.html');
</script>
```