# Using javascript for an off-server page-dynamic links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the HTML and CSS down the pat, but I'm needing some javascript to tie this all together.

I have a page 'static.html' that does not exist on a server, but rather a local filesystem.

This file has a `div` layout with 2 lists of names/titles/etc. along with a CSS stylesheet to style all the static pages.
The page also uses an inline media player.  These pages are designed to be used offline, off-server, and thus have very limited functionality.

I would like to change the lists to `a href=` links to other static pages, however not all the titles/names in the list have pages currently, or may not need them.

Is there a way that I can use some javascript to check if the `href="./linkedpage.html"` exists and then turn on/off the link on page load.

I can create one parent page that references 30 other pages, and as I add the new pages, the links can become active within the parent.

Ideally, this script can be loaded on every page to check the links' source to be present or not, and enable/disable the anchor tag.

Thanks a bunch,
-Tim

EDIT: PS. the `href` links will be images and text.

Edit: Working progress Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function checkLink(someLink)
{
  var tmp=new Image;
  tmp.src=someLink;
  if(tmp.complete)
    {window.open(someLink,"_self");}
  else
    {return 0;}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="javascript:checkLink('./page1.html');">Title 1</a>
<a href="javascript:checkLink('./page2.html');">Title 2</a>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a page1.html in the same directory, but no page2.html...both links return 0. Debugger returns "Error: Incorrect contents fetched, please reload."

Revised, for testing...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function checkLink(someLink)
{
  var tmp=new Image;
  tmp.src=someLink;
  if(tmp.complete)
    {window.open(someLink,"_self");}
  else
    {return 0;}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" onclick="checkLink('./page1.html'); return false; ">Title 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="checkLink('./page2.html'); return false; ">Title 2</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Now it does nothing.

Comment: May you include a bit of your code?

Comment: There's no easy way, but you can use Fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch , check the response code to be in the 200s and then is valid

Comment: Are you trying to check if the page exist on server with local file? Do you run that local file on local server or just on browser?

Comment: @A.Meshu Basically it will be a html navigation of a local file archive to be used only in the browser on an offline machine.

Comment: I don't think that is possible without using (local) server. But maybe someone else can hack this...

Comment: I stole that little function from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226410/check-html-file-exist-on-server-using-javascript, I intend to change return 0 to #, keeps on the same page.

Comment: @clota974 code included, and revised, included...

Comment: @DvidSilva I'm not sure how to use fetch, I'm good with html, css, batch, and a bit of C, but not java.  Not really a programmer.  However, it seems to me, an API call requires network access, and that is not guaranteed for this webpage.